# Can I use "any" with an object expressed in plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Which one is correct?

1. > "Any letter"
2. > "Any letters"

> Let me provide the context:
>   "Are there any letters in the post box?"

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: Context would help.

Comment: @bib - I have edited my question and provided the context.

Comment: Both are correct, in the appropriate contexts.  "Pick any letter" would mean select one from the group that is presented.  "Pick any letters" would mean pick one or more from said group.  "Are there any letters today?" inquires whether there was any mail today.

Comment: And in your sample sentence the plurality of "letters" must match the plurality of the verb "are".  So it would have to be "Is there any letter in the post box?" if not plural.

Comment: @Hot Licks - Do you say "Are there any letters in the post box?" is correct? I am confused a little. Please help me.

Comment: Either "Are there any letters" or "Is there any letter".  The latter would imply that you were expecting a specific letter, vs just inquiring as to whether the mail had arrived yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Any is normally used with plural and uncountable nouns in questions, negative and conditional sentences. We would normally require a/an before a singular countable noun. However, when we want to emphasise that any means of any kind, it is quite natural to use any with singular uncountable nouns." This has been nicely explained in detail at http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv303.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use it in a sentence? Rand is right, both are correct... though in certain contexts I can see how one might be less appropriate or might contradict the intended meaning of what you're trying to say.

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the context. Can you please enlighten me now?

Comment: Hm, you seem to know which is correct for the context of the example you've provided. 'Any' implies that the numerical quantity is unimportant and thus inclusive of all quantities. The answer to the question is yes regardless of whether there is a single letter or a thousand letters in the post box.

Answer (score 0):

We use "any letters" when we mean "one or more" and we use "any letter" when we mean "it doesn't matter which one."